# Regex + operator not matching as many times as possible

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following text:

```
/*
a bunch of lines of text here
*/
#ifndef header
#define header
#include "include1.h"
#include "include2.h"
#ifndef SOME_TYPEDEF
#define SOME_TYPEDEF
...etc
```

I'm trying to use regex to match everything after the include statements with the following line of code:

```
Regex.Match(myText, @"(?<=(#include "".+""\r\n)+).*").ToString();
```

When I run this code, the result of the match is:

```
#include "include2.h"
```

I can ditch the lookbehind and use the following regex:

```
Regex.Match(myText, @"(#include "".+""\r\n)+").ToString();
```

When I do this, I match both include statements as expected, but for some reason when I add the lookbehind it only matches one. I can fix it with the following code:

```
Regex.Match(simulinkTypes, @"(?<=(#include "".+""\r\n){2,}).*").ToString();
```

This regex gives me the first line after both include statements which is what I need. However, I can't assume that there will always be at least two include statements. Why doesn't + work?

Comment: You may try `Regex.Match(myText, @"(?:#include\s+"".+""\r\n)+(?s)(.*)").Groups[1].Value`

Comment: This worked. Can you explain why it works please?

Comment: First, consume all `include` lines, then capture the rest of the string. However, parsing code with a single regex is not safe.